# Javascript optimization: repetition of a same function

Tags: javascript

I want to use a getElemendbyId function several times, just by passing the name of the ID as a variable.

I guess there is a more elegant way to do it than:

```
<div id="1" onclick="myFunction2()"></div>
<div id="2" onclick="myFunction3()"></div>
<div id="3" onclick="myFunction4()"></div>
<div id="4" onclick="myFunction5()"></div>
<script>
function myFunction2() { document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = "test2"; }
function myFunction3() { document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "test3"; }
function myFunction4() { document.getElementById("4").innerHTML = "test4"; }
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new function and move everything that is shared in that function. Make the things that are variable parameters of that function.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id="1" onclick="myFunction(2, 'test2')"></div>
<div id="2" onclick="myFunction(3, 'test3')"></div>
<div id="3" onclick="myFunction(4, 'test4')"></div>
<div id="4" onclick="myFunction(5, 'test5')"></div>
<script>
    function myFunction(id, content) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = content; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to go about this, but in all scenarios you really should not use inline event handling attributes (`onclick`). There are [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991) not to use this 20+ year old technique that just will not die the death it deserved to almost 10 years ago. Additionally, don't use `.innerHTML` to get/set values that don't contain any HTML as it is wasteful, in terms of performance and it opens up security holes in your application. Instead, use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get/set non-HTML values.

**For each element to have its own handler:**

1. Get all the elements that need a similar handler into an array
2. Loop over the array
3. Assign a handler to the current array element

```js
// Get all the elements that need the same handler into an Array
let divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div"));

// Iterate the array
divs.forEach(function(div){
  // Set up the handler
  div.addEventListener("click", function(){
    div.textContent = "test" + div.id;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="1">click me</div>
<div id="2">click me</div>
<div id="3">click me</div>
<div id="4">click me</div>
```

**To set up just one handler and use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation):**

1. Assign a common handler to an ancestor of all the elements in question
2. In the handler, act upon the specific element that triggered the event.

```js
// Set up an event handler on the container element
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Act upon the target of the event (the element that triggered the
  // event in the first place).
  event.target.textContent = "test" + event.target.id;
});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="1">click me</div>
  <div id="2">click me</div>
  <div id="3">click me</div>
  <div id="4">click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189154/discussion-on-answer-by-scott-marcus-javascript-optimization-repetition-of-a-sa).

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution than inline [`on<...>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) event handlers is to call `addEventListener` on the parent element ([read about **event delegation** here](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)). Once the listener is registered you can use the `event` argument to determine what target the user has clicked and what action to be taken, if any.

For example, in the scenario below we evaluate the `event` to determine if one of our `<div>` elements were clicked - if so, call `myFunction` with the appropriate data passed in:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick)

function handleClick(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'DIV') {
    myFunction(event.target);
  }
}

function myFunction(el) {
  el.innerHTML = `test${el.id}`;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">Click Me</div>
<div id="2">Click Me</div>
<div id="3">Click Me</div>
<div id="4">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) functions. It looks like this

```js
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(id => {
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('click', () => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id + 1);
    if (el) el.innerHTML = `test${id+1}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='1'>a</div>
<div id='2'>b</div>
<div id='3'>c</div>
<div id='4'>d</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without using Ids

```js
function myFunction(el, content) {
   el.innerHTML = content; 
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction(this, 'test2')">Click Me</div>
<div onclick="myFunction(this, 'test3')">Click Me</div>
<div onclick="myFunction(this, 'test4')">Click Me</div>
<div onclick="myFunction(this, 'test5')">Click Me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Event Delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm)

Event delegation is a pattern that optimizes event handling by registering an ancestor element of a group of descendant elements. By controlling what is ignored and what is triggered by an event, you can have a single element (ancestor in demo is `<ul>`/ [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)) listen for an event (click event in demo) for all of its descendant elements (all of the `<li>` in demo [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)).

---

### Demo

**Details are commented in demo**

```js
// Reference an ancestor element
var list = document.querySelector('ul');
// Register click event on ancestor element
list.onclick = clicker;
// Callback function pass the Event Object
function clicker(event) {
  // Reference the clicked element (<li>...)
  var clicked = event.target;
  // Reference the element registered to the event (<ul>)
  var ancestor = event.currentTarget;
  // if the clicked element is NOT the registered element
  if (clicked !== ancestor) {
    // if the clicked element is an <li>...
    if (clicked.matches('li')) {
      // ...toggle the .on class 
      clicked.classList.toggle('on');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.on {
  color: gold;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ITEM 1</li>
  <li>ITEM 2</li>
  <li>ITEM 3</li>
  <li>ITEM 4</li>
</ul>
```